# Streamline Facebook and Google Play Game Services integration in Android Game

Tags: android, facebook, google-play-games, social-gaming

This has been confusing me a lot .

I am creating a simple 2D platformer which I wish to make social. So I thought of letting users do the following:

- Share their in game objective completion/ their high score etc with their friends.
- Challenge their friends to have a better score / better multiplier etc from their's
- View leaderboards of high score , most distance traveled etc both social and global.

So My First preference was Facebook , simply because people have better social connections there.

But then Google Play game services integration has another advantage, It makes you game available in their game services app and may be boost your game ranking in play store if you have game services integrated. But then I'' need to have leaderboards(same ones) for google plus as well. That 'll be too confusing for people.

I do not want people to sign in twice in my app. That'll simple cut down and disperse the number of people getting social with the game.

I personally want to use facebook alone but then google game services may be boosts my app in store.

Can someone tell me a solution to use them both frictionlessly and get the most out of them in my game

Answer (score 1):

It is quite common to include multiple social networks in games. Have a look at something like [ASNE](https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE) wich makes this process much easier.

Alternately, you could use Google Play Game Services for leaderboards/achievements and then add "share" buttons (or some kind of "opt in" and automatic sharing) to share scores (or whatever) when needed to Facebook.

Because these kind of logins only require authorization once it should not be a problem to request login to more than one social network - game launches after this initial authorization would usually not require any interaction from the user - but be sure to allow them to log out, in case they want to stop this behaviour.

If you do intend to share scores via facebook, just be aware that unlike every other social network, sharing text using the default Android `ACTION_SEND` intent **does not work** - Facebook only allows sharing URLs this way. You will need to use either the official Facebook Android SDK or some library such as ASNE (mentioned above).